# Angular 2 how to merge two equal index arrays into one?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

For example if I have Two equal index arrays:

```
A [
{name: Jhon}
{name: Jacob}
{name: Lukas}
]

B [
{fr: Prince} //fr, en, it is language, Prince is LastName
{en: Breed}
{it: Lasontos}
]
```

How to merge it to one so It would look like this :

```
 A [
    {name: Jhon, lastname: Prince, country: fr }
    {name: Jacob, lastname: Breed, country: en}
    {name: Lukas, lastname: Lasontos, country: it}
    ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Object.assign(obj1, obj2)` and `map()` method applied on the first object array.

```
var arr = [
  {firstname: 'John'},
  {firstname: 'Hello'}
]

var arr2 = [
  {fr: 'Here'},
  {en: 'There'}
]

arr.map((obj, index) => {

  var internalization = {
    country: Object.keys(arr2[index])[0],
    lastname: arr2[index][Object.keys(arr2[index])[0]]
  }

  return Object.assign(obj, internalization);
})

console.log(arr);
```

**Working fiddle:**

https://jsbin.com/wepibuwazi/1/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 1):

If your objects in the B array are always only going to have the one property, then the following code should do it, though this is a strange way to use an object. If you have control over the structure of B, I would recommend setting the entries to be an object with a lastname property and a country property, rather than using the country as the key. That way you can use Andrei's original answer.

```
var A = [
  {name: Jhon}
  {name: Jacob}
  {name: Lukas}
]

var B = [
  {fr: Prince} //fr, en, it is language, Prince is LastName
  {en: Breed}
  {it: Lasontos}
]

A.map((obj, index) => {
  var keys = Object.keys(B[index]);
  obj.country = keys[0];
  obj.lastname = B[index][keys[0]];
  return obj;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```js
let A = [
         {name: 'Jhon'},
         {name: 'Jacob'},
         {name: 'Lukas'}
        ]

let B = [
         {fr: 'Prince'},
         {en: 'Breed'},
         {it: 'Lasontos'},
        ]

 for(let i in B){
   let temp = Object.keys(B[i])[0];
   A[i].country = temp
   A[i].lastname = B[i][temp];
 }

console.log(A)
```